# Android ImageView Transition with transition manager act weird

Tags: android, animation, transition, android-4.4-kitkat, scene

I'm using android's new transition manager comes with 4.4 Kit-Kat.

I have two scenes for this `imageView` as shown below:

**expanded_scene.xml**

```
<ImageView
                android:id="@+id/avatar"
                android:layout_width="125dp"
                android:layout_height="125dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/avatar"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/avatar"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
```

**collapsed_scene.xml**

```
<ImageView
                android:id="@+id/avatar"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/avatar"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/avatar"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
```

**change_bounds.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <changeBounds/>
```

**transition_mgr.xml**

```
<transitionManager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <transition
        android:toScene="@layout/collapsed_scene"
        android:transition="@anim/change_bounds"/>
    <transition
        android:toScene="@layout/expanded_scene"
        android:transition="@anim/change_bounds"/>

</transitionManager>
```

**Code**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ViewGroup mSceneRoot;
    private Scene mSceneExpanded;
    private Scene mSceneCollapsed;
    private TransitionManager mTransitionManager;
    private boolean collapse;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mSceneRoot = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.sceneRoot);
        TransitionInflater inflater = TransitionInflater.from(this);


        mSceneExpanded = Scene.getSceneForLayout(mSceneRoot, R.layout.expanded_scene, this);
        mSceneCollapsed = Scene.getSceneForLayout(mSceneRoot, R.layout.collapsed_scene, this);
        mTransitionManager = inflater.inflateTransitionManager(R.anim.transitions_mgr,
                mSceneRoot);

        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mTransitionManager.transitionTo(collapse ?mSceneCollapsed:mSceneExpanded);

                collapse = !collapse;
            }
        });

    }
}
```

When i use transition from expanded to collapse scene, image is resized without animation then is animated to its coordinate. 
If i change scenes backwards, image goes to new coordinate then resize with animation.

I only use `<changeBounds/>` in `transitionSet`

How can i animate bounds at the same time ?

Comment: Here is the video of animation : https://www.dropbox.com/s/vsg7jzbk3z87j3x/VID20140321154034.mp4